# How to load this big size hadoop file?

Tags: linux, hadoop

How to load this big size **hadoop** file?

I need to load some files from **hadoop** to local USB.

One file in a directory is strange, it only has a name "-", and the size of it is over 45G. I first use `hadoop fs -get` to get the data to local **linux VM**, and then use **WinSCP** to load the data to local USB. But my local **Linux VM**'s capacity  is only 19G. How to do this?

I am thinking about splitting the 45G file to smaller files using **hadoop** command. But I have not found such command.

Comment: Just mount the USB into the VM

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following :

1. Use `hadoop fs -get` command and save all the data into the VM's disk.
2. Use `split -b 10240K hadoopfile splitflie` , which splits your files per 10GB.
3. Move each part file to your USB.
4. At your destination use `cat splitfile* > hadoopfile` , to combine it a single file.